# summarise() in dplyr ignores the groups that have already been created in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a tibble that contains monthly observations:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

mfs.dataframe <- structure(
  list(
    Date = structure(
      c(
        17197,
        17225,
        17256,
        17286,
        17317,
        17347,
        17378,
        17409,
        17439,
        17470
      ),
      class = "Date"
    ),
    m2 = c(
      9586.1485960711,
      10133.2515139652,
      10692.0071143624,
      10442.8613115585,
      10352.354832707,
      10763.0662099058,
      10869.735010259,
      11174.5131264841,
      11678.0194789741,
      11548.8304023101
    ),
    private_sector_claims = c(
      5836.3121609,
      5811.50043440506,
      5841.654446964,
      5801.247438522,
      5981.69435068,
      5934.79495271,
      5936.83241575,
      5967.327903756,
      6160.67429487,
      6068.69840886
    ),
    business_ent_claims = c(
      2166.00848066912,
      2071.38826678,
      2102.46072741634,
      2065.760912972,
      2179.23061007,
      2100.98313658,
      1989.63394849,
      2051.25948937,
      1967.7576887,
      1999.08408221
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-10L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

I want to express in quarters, however since these are stocks, I have to take positions at the end of each quarter. I have this code:

```
mfs.dataframe <- mfs_df |> dplyr::mutate(
  qdate = as.yearqtr(Date))
```

then code above creates a column with quarterly dates - qdate (i.e. 2017 Q1) however when I group using the column qdate to take the last observation of the group the code returns the last observation of the whole tibble

here is the code that I used:

```
mfsQtrly <- mfs_df |> 
  group_by(qdate) |> 
  summarise(qdate = last(qdate),
            m2 = last(m2),
            private_sector_claims = last(private_sector_claims),
            total_deposits = last(total_deposits))
```

this only results in a tibble with 4 vars and 1 observation, it ignores the groups

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(mfs_df)`, if that is not too large. And remember to include all libraries in code: it's not apparent, for example, that `as.yearqtr` requires the `zoo` package.

Comment: Thank you neilfws, I have tried to add the data

Comment: The  code starts out defining mfs.dataframe and then clobbers it using mfs.df but mfs.df is not defined. Please fix the code in the question to make it self consistent.